# assets folder wasn't created in android app whan using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I try to create a mobile app using stand-alone phonegap. When I use the following coding

```
D:\phonegap-2.8.0\lib\android\bin>create \foldername myapp.package.com proname
```

there is no assets folder created in the project folder. What can be the reason for that?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't get created automatically. You will have to create it on your own. Use [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html) tutorial to make a move.

Comment: Thanks Jayram!, But in my first try the assets folder was created. But in second try I cannot do that. I used phonegap for it.